# Getting data from page to program

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitView` and i am trying to populate the left side controller with values from a database.
I have this phpcode.

```
    $query = "SELECT name FROM country";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $json_output[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($json_output);
```

However when i come into my ios app. I have this code in my `viewDidLoad`

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php"];
NSArray *test= [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
 TypesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:test];
```

and in `cellforRowAtIndexpat`
I added

```
cell.textLabel.text=[TypesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Therefore, when I run my program I expect to see my values listed in the `leftviewcontroller`, but sadly it shows up blank.The `NSLog` also shows up null, would like some help as to why my values are not being pulled to my app.

Thanks

Comment: can you insert next code after NSURL* myURL... : NSError* error = nil;NSString* str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: myURL]                                                        encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: &error]; NSLog(@"%@", str); ?

Comment: do you know how to pars json or xml.? please learn it and do some RND for it in google.

Comment: @NitinGohel Well I have actually used that json before in another app i was doing an it worked. Does my problem lie in my program not receiving anything from the link?

Comment: @stosha I changed my php and it returns values in the browser. but the program is still showing nulls

Comment: check that your real url string contains "http://" protocol

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php"]]
                                                           cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval: 60.0];

NSData* responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request
                                                 returningResponse: nil
                                                             error: nil];
if (responseData)
{
    NSArray* array = [[JSONDecoder decoder] parseJSONData: responseData];
    NSLog(@"%@", [array description]);
}
```

where JSONDecoder you can take by link  https://github.com/hollyschinsky/PGPushNotificationSample

Comment: I changed it, still blanks in my leftview controller, the nslog is null, however my php link gives me back [{"name":"England"},{"name":"America"},{"name":"Phillipians"}]

Comment: There are many files in the folder, not exactly sure which to import to access JSONDecoder. Also i dont understand this method...nor why my method doesnt work

Comment: I actually only just now your comment concerning "http" turns out that was what I was missing. i took it for granted and just typed www.

Comment: sadly thou i still dont see anything in my viewcontroller. I tried saying TypesArray=[[NSMutableArray clloc]initWithContentsofURL:myURL]; didnt work so i put myURL in an array an said TypesArray[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:sqlResults]; Neither puts the values in the leftviewcontroller as i hoped